# Can I use yield inside a view component in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the `view_component` gem for Rails.
I like to do something like below.

```
// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render BodyComponent.new %>
</body>
</html>
```

```
// app/components/body_component.html.erb
<div class="container">
  <%= render HeaderComponent.new %>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render FooterComponent.new %>
</div>
```

I wonder if this is possible at all ? Currently I get `LocalJumpError in MyController. no block given (yield)`

Comment: What do you anticipate `yield` doing here?

Comment: I wanted yield to render the correct controller action view there. So below answer did solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yield` is a ruby keyword, and if no block is provided to the calling method then a `LocalJumpError` is expected.

I've not used a view component, but [from their documentation](https://viewcomponent.org/guide/#implementation/) you can pass it a block in ERB which will get rendered with the `content` keyword.

The problem though is that you want to *forward* the  whatever block is provided to the method that renders your rails view in a layout, to your view component. The only way I know of forwarding a block requires you to be in control of the method signature, which you aren't here: https://joeyates.info/2014/06/30/how-to-forward-blocks-in-ruby/

What you can do is to store the results of rendering a rails layout in a variable, like this:

```rb
<% my_rendered_content = yield %>
```

and do something with `my_rendered_content` in your ViewComponent. But this sounds like it might get painful quickly, if for example your ViewComponent starts trying to escape the already-rendered html. What I guess you can do is to use the `content` helper inside your

```
// app/components/body_component.html.erb
<div class="container">
  <%= render HeaderComponent.new %>
  <%= content %>
  <%= render FooterComponent.new %>
</div>
```

Then use it like this:

```
// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render BodyComponent.new do %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>

</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively the [slots API](https://viewcomponent.org/guide/slots.html) might suit your needs better?

Comment: the link for the ViewComponent documentation seems to be broken, however https://viewcomponent.org/guide/getting-started.html#implementation seem to point to the new home for the `content` accessor

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like below.

```
// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body>
  <% main_content = yield %>
  <%= render BodyComponent.new(main_content) %>
</body>
```

```
class BodyComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  attr_reader :main_content

  def initialize(main_content)
    @main_content = main_content
  end
end
```

```
<div class="container">
  <%= render HeaderComponent.new %>
  <%= main_content.html_safe %>
  <%= render FooterComponent.new %>
</div>
```

However I like the solution by @rworld better.

```
// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body>
  <%= render BodyComponent.new do %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

```
<div class="container">
  <%= render HeaderComponent.new %>
  <%= content %>
  <%= render FooterComponent.new %>
</div>
```